# How to use a function without first running the function script first?

Tags: r, function

This may be a silly question as I am new to R. I wrote a function that sums the square of two inputs. but I can't figure out how to directly use the function every time I open R without first running the function's script. Any help is appreciated.

```
sum.of.squares <- function(x,y) {
  x^2 + y^2
}
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple things:

1. Include this function in your `Rprofile` file (See [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html))
2. Save an image of your environment as `.RData` (See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html)). Whenever you start an `R` session from that directory, the `.Rdata` file with the function will be loaded.

Comment: Can you explain? I often have helper functions saved as part of my R environment that I don't want to be loaded globally between different projects (that all use the same R binary).

Comment: Storing stuff in your environment means it's hard to see what's there (outside of R) and hard to document.  Better to put helper functions into .R files and source() them -- or write a package, once they get complicated.